# How to apply Javascript conditionally on a specific css-class only?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am using a responsive JavaScript menu with a toggle button in a Wordpress Genesis site.

The page has a primary CSS menu (`.nav-primary`) and a secondary CSS menu (`.nav-secondary`). The main navigation styling classes are `.genesis-nav-menu` and `.sub-menu`.

The problem is that the responsive menu is applied to every navigation element on the site, i.e. you have at least 2 toogle bars. I would like to use it only for the primary menu (`.nav-primary`).

I already tried to substitute 'nav' with `.nav-primary`, which seems to work, however it makes the ´secondary-menu´ and all other navigation elements disappear.

I would appreciate your advice how to get this done.

**The Javascript:**

```
( function( window, $, undefined ) {
    'use strict';

    $( 'nav' ).before( '<button class="menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>' ); // Add toggles to menus
    $( 'nav .sub-menu' ).before( '<button class="sub-menu-toggle" role="button" aria-pressed="false"></button>' ); // Add toggles to sub menus

    // Show/hide the navigation
    $( '.menu-toggle, .sub-menu-toggle' ).on( 'click', function() {
        var $this = $( this );
        $this.attr( 'aria-pressed', function( index, value ) {
            return 'false' === value ? 'true' : 'false';
        });

        $this.toggleClass( 'activated' );
        $this.next( 'nav, .sub-menu' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );

    });

})( this, jQuery );
```

Comment: Use `.nav-primary`, not just `nav-primary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(".nav-primary")` selector for the class nav-primary, not `$("nav-primary")`.

Here you have information about [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: ´.nav-secondary´ is not showing up any longer in this way.